# Add 1 for every multiple of 7 difference

Tags: c, math

This is a combined math and Objective C question

I`m stuck in writing the logic of the following:

The user will enter a number, lets say 1000, then i want to subtract this number from 1013, get the difference which is 13.

Now I have a number , lets say 50, I want to add 1 to this number for every difference of 7 between the above numbers

Again

```
int userEnteredNumber = 1000;
int referenceNumber = 1013;
int difference = referenceNumber - userEnteredNumber;//which is 13

//For every difference of 7 add 1 to someNumber
int someNumber = ????? + 1;

//this is where I`m stuck with, i.e. if difference is 6 for example I would add 1, if difference is 13 I would add 2 and so on
```

I know how to do it mentally but not in code.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have update one condition, Please follow and let me know am i understood correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have in someNumber the number of times one number have 7, so you should divide that number by 7 and round it up, then you'll have it.

Use ceil function if you want to round up: 3.123 => 4 or use round if you want to round based on the argument: 3.123 => 3 or 3.7 => 4

```
{
    int userEnteredNumber = 1000;
    int referenceNumber = 1013;
    int difference = referenceNumber - userEnteredNumber;//which is 13

    //For every difference of 7 add 1 to someNumber
    int someNumber = ceil(difference / 7.0f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alex, actually found the answer before your reply using ceil() function, as the numberTobeSubtracted from eg.50 should be rounded up and not down.

Answer (score 1):

`someNumber = difference + floor(difference / 7);`

Comment: Using `floor(double)` seems superfluous. Plain old integer division should do it. But you need to add something to get the rounding the OP wants (he doesn't specify exactly what he wants, though).

Comment: You are right. I didn't think of that he is just using integers... :)

Comment: Can't you simply say `(difference+1)/7`?

Comment: @devnull You can say `(difference+k)/7` where k is between 1 and 6. The OP hasn't specified the value of k in the question.

Comment: Found it , sorry if it was not clear, I ended up using ceil()